# My app fails to connect to the server some times

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, http, afnetworking

I've been helplessly observing this problem for a couple months now, and have decided this is my best shot.

I'm not sure what the cause of the problem is, but I can list some of the things I'm doing. I have an iOS app that uses AFNetworking to connect to a remote server hosted by Google App Engine using HTTP POST requests.

Now, everything works great, but sometimes, very very sporadically and random, I get failed requests. The activity indicator spins and spins for about a minute, and I get no feedback at the end - just a failed request. I check my server logs, and I don't see any errors. After the failed request, I try again, and it works fine. It works fine for the whole day. And then another time randomly the issue repeats itself, sometimes spinning for 10 seconds with a fail, or a minute.

Generally, what can possibly be the cause of this? Is it normal to have some failed connections randomly? Is that something on my part?

But the weird thing is, is that while on my iPhone the app is running, and the indicator is spinning, and it's trying to connect, I try connecting on the iOS simulator, and the connection works just fine. I try again on the iPhone, and it doesn't work.

If I close the app completely and start again, then it works again. So it sounds like it may be a software issue rather than connection issue, but then again I have no evidence or data what so ever.

I know it's vague, but I'm hoping someone may have had a similar problem. Anything helps.

Comment: No information about this in your app engine log? Do you retry when your first request times out? Do you pay for your app engine application and what about latency?

Comment: @voscausa no there's nothing about it in my app engine log. When I retry after the first time out, it usually works again. I'm still in development phase so it's still the free version of GAE, and nothing unusual about latency..

Comment: We have had the same kind of issue with ajax calls and we assumed that it was a latency / instance warm-up related. We solved it using a timeout and request retries.

Comment: @voscausa ya I thought it might be a warm up issue too, but when the request fails on one device, if I try on another, it works fine. If I try again on the original device, it doesn't work until I restart the app. I'm thinking it might be a mix of both warm up issues + software issues on my end, probably something to do with AFNetworking being confused after the first failed request. But there are total guesses, I really have no idea where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue with instance start on GAE for Java. You can star http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7706 issue.

The same problem was reported for Python but it is not such a big problem.

I think you should check logging level you use on appengine and monitor all your calls. Instance start usually takes more time, so you will be able to see how much time do you use on start and is it really a timeout problem.

For Java version you could try to change log level to debug:

```
.level = DEBUG
```

in your logging.properties file. It will give you more information about instance start process.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. The question is, how would I know if it's a GAE issue or an issue with the networking framework I'm using on the client side? Usually, the first request fails, and all subsequent requests succeed. However, yesterday the requests kept failing, one after the other, but only on one device. On another device, the requests succeeded. So I'm thinking it's a combination of both GAE issues and AFNetworking issues, but I'm not sure where to debug with AFNetworking..

Comment: May be you should add some device ID as an URL request parameter. This will help you to distinguish requests. And if you will find your requests on AppEngine than you can start to look to an issue on Server Side.